# VB.NET Address Pointer

Tags: vb.net

I have a DLL with the following function and is being used in my application

```
WritetoBuffer(BYTE* pBuffer, DATA_TYPE Type);
```

This is the code being used in VB 6

```
Dim pBuffer() as byte
ReDim pBuffer(0 To (300 * 400 * 3 - 1))
Dim ppBuf As Long
ppBuf = VarPtr(pImageBuffer(0))                                             
Dim Rtn As Integer
Rtn = WritetoBuffer(ppBuf, 1)
```

I am trying to write the equivalent code in VB.NET, but I am facing difficulties in it. Tried using the following function, but it's not working.

```
 Public Function VarPtr(ByVal e As Object) As Intptr
        Dim GC As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(e, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Dim GC2 As Intptr = GC.AddrOfPinnedObject.ToInt32
        GC.Free()
        Return GC2
    End Function
```

I haven't used Marshal Class or similar functions before and I am not sure about the right way to do it. Can someone please advice me on this?

Comment: Your VB6 code doesn't explain what `pImageBuffer` is or where it came from. Also, what is `DATA_TYPE`? I note that calling `IntPtr.ToInt32` and then assigning back to an `IntPtr` variable is pointless (and dangerous/unworkable on x64 systems).

Comment: Your code probably needs to keep the handle to `e` alive for as long as you're using the buffer address, otherwise you're depending on the memory not being relocated during runtime (i.e. undefined behaviour). Why can't you pin an object properly with the `fixed` keyword?

Comment: I am sorry. It's not pImageBuffer(0) it is pBuffer.

Comment: you don't need to know what data_type or what is pBuffer doing. You know the code work in VB6. He's asking help to put it in VB.NET.

Comment: @Dai I think his WriteToBuffer function is a 32 bits and won't necessarily run pass 32bits limit

Comment: @Chillzy The value of the pointer returned by `GC.AddrOfPinnedObject` may be above `2^32`, so calling `ToInt32()` will result in an invalid/meaningless address value which is subsequently dereferenced - this is undefined behaviour and grounds for a program crash.

Comment: Just declare the pBuffer argument as `ByVal buffer() As Byte`.  Do beware that this function is very, very dangerous, you'll corrupt the GC heap when you pass an array that is not big enough.  Excessively hard to debug.

Comment: @Dai maybe but it could also crash depending on how his old function works. The other thing is unless you work with Option Strict On vb.NET will try to cast a int32 if that's type getting pass to the function.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dai commented, `.ToInt32` is incorrect here, and you can’t free the handle before you use it.

```
Dim pBuffer(300 * 400 * 3 - 1) As Byte
Dim pinned = GCHandle.Alloc(pBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim Rtn As Integer = WritetoBuffer(pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 1)
pinned.Free()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need GCHandle to stay alive while you make your call. Just returning the address of the pointer is not enough from what I understand. When you're done then free the handle.

```
Dim Handle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim ppbuf As IntPtr = Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject.ToInt32
Dim Rtn As Integer
Rtn = WritetoBuffer(ppbuf, 1)
Handle.Free()
```

Comment: To avoid memory leaks you should wrap the whole thing in a [**`Try/Finally`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement), then free the handle inside `Finally` only if `Handle.IsAllocated = True`. This way if an exception occurs the `Handle.Free()` code will still be executed, otherwise the object would be locked forever (until the process exits).

Comment: Also, as already noted you **must not** call `AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt32()` because an `IntPtr` could definitely be larger than 2^32, and it has nothing to do with what his function is or does. A pointer is a memory address and is not related to the functions bitness or behaviour.

Comment: @VisualVincent it's still going to crash if the function written in 32bits is not able to access a pointer beyond the 32bits limit and unless you are working with Option Strict On all this is irrelevant

Comment: After coming to my senses I might be able to explains this more properly: The thing about why one shouldn't call `ToInt32()` is because an `IntPtr` adapts to the process's bitness. If the process is 32-bit then the `IntPtr` will be an Int32, likewise if the process is 64-bit the `IntPtr` will be an Int64. The DLL that is loaded must be of the exact same bitness as the process. Therefore you can never have a DLL that _**doesn't**_ support as large pointers as the process does. If the process is 64-bit then the DLL must be so as well for it to work at all.

Answer (score -1):

In cases such as this you shouldn't need to get a pointer of your byte array. Due to the fact that since `BYTE* pBuffer` is used as an array, that is all you need it to be in VB.NET as well.

Thus you could declare your P/Invoke like this:

```
<DllImport("yourfile.dll")> _
Public Shared Function WritetoBuffer(ByVal pBuffer As Byte(), ByVal Type As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

...and then use it like this:

```
Dim pBuffer() as byte
ReDim pBuffer(0 To (300 * 400 * 3 - 1))

Dim Rtn As Integer = WritetoBuffer(pBuffer, 1)
```